# No tengo resolucion 1920x1200

Tags: linux, ubuntu

luego de instalar el driver de nvidia no tengo la resolucion que siempre utilizo en esta maquina 1920x1200 este es mi Xorg.conf

```
    # nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 415.27

#Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapLimit"             # <i>
        #Option     "AsyncUTSDFS"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <i>
#    Identifier     "Card0"
#    Driver         "nouveau"
#    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
#EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath        "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 55.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0 
   Modeline "1920x1200_60.00" 193.25 1920 2056 2256 2592 1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro K620"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "1920x1200 +0+0; nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "1920x1200 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1600x900 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes "1920x1200"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Agrego la informacion del comando xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1600x900      59.82* 
   1400x900      59.88  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.96    59.80  
   1280x800      59.91    59.81  
   1280x720      59.86    59.74  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x576      59.90    59.82  
   960x540       59.82    59.63  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   800x450       59.82  
   700x450       59.88  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   640x400       59.98    59.88  
   640x360       59.86    59.83  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.82    59.63  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Salida del comando cvt 1920 1200:

```
# 1920x1200 59.88 Hz (CVT 2.30MA) hsync: 74.56 kHz; pclk: 193.25 MHz
Modeline "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
```

Comment: ¿Qué te devuelve el siguiente comando: `xrandr`?

Comment: @MauricioContreras se agrego la informacion solicitada

Comment: Bien, vamos a intentar añadir manualmente la resolución que necesitas. Si los comentarios se hacen muy largos pasaremos al chat. Escribe el siguiente comando: `cvt 1920 1200`, y añade el resultado a tu respuesta

Comment: @MauricioContreras añadida la salida del comando cvt

Comment: Muy bien, ahora agregarás la siguiente línea a tu archivo Xorg.conf: En la sección `Monitor` agregas la siguiente línea: `Modeline "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync`. Luego, en la sección `Screen` busca la subsección `Display` y agrega la siguiente linea: `Modes "1920x1200"`. Salva tu archivo, y reinicia el equipo. Comenta los resultados. Una sugerencia previa: haz una copia de respaldo del archivo, en caso que algo falle puedas revertir los cambios.

Comment: @MauricioContreras agrege el nuevo Xorg con los cambios que me solicitastes pero el problema continua, desde ningun lado puedo pasar a 1920 ni desde la conf de Nvidia ni desde la configuracion de Gnome, solo llego a 1600x900

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90022/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-sebastian).